# Oracle, Complex condition on a subquery

Tags: oracle

**Complex condition on a subquery , I have a complex query with code and output below**

```
Query :
select * from
(select item , value, date, day
from dual)
```

output :

```
item  | value |   date  | day
item1 |   5  |1/1/2020 |  1
item2 |   20  |1/1/2020 |  1
item1 |   1   |2/1/2020 |  2
item2 |   3   |2/1/2020 |  2
item1 |   35  |3/1/2020 |  3
item2 |   3  |3/1/2020 |  3
```

Needed : Select only rows with days having sum of (values) > 10 on the same day

```
item  |  value | date    | day
item1 |   5   |1/1/2020 | 1
item2 |   20   |1/1/2020 | 1
item1 |   35   |3/1/2020 | 3
item2 |   3   |3/1/2020 | 3
```

needed to select all rows with the condition applied

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Please properly tag the database you are running.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Oracle  added to question thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Select only rows with days having sum of (values) > 10 on the same day

You can use a window `sum()` to compute the total values per day in a subquery, then filter in the outer query:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, sum(value) over(partition by day) sum_value
    from mytable t
) t
where sum_value > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

This addresses the original question:

I think this is just `group by` and `having`:

```
select item, sum(value), date day
from t
group by item, date, day
having sum(value) > 10;
```

Or, in the example data you have, aggregation may not even be necessary:

```
select t.*
from t
where value > 10;
```

EDIT:

For the revised question, you want window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(value) over (partition by item, date, date) as total_value
      from t
     ) t
where total_value > 10
```

Comment: working get only days with values > 10 , but i want all values of this day if their sum > 10